# How to set bar-colors manually in order of factor-values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I'm trying to make two bar-charts within one frame with 'ggplot2' and 'facet_grid', it worked very well. But now I want to set the colors of the bars (4 for both plots) manually, to - let's say - green, blue, red and orange (in this order). In the code below the colors of the bars depend on the variable 'V1' which has four levels/values, 1 up to 4. I tried to set 'fill' to a vector-column with four colors, but it didn't work. I tried to make an example with mtcars (see below). And one for my df (further down) Maybe someone knows how to alter this code. in order two choose your own color per bar

```
# mtcars

p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, fill = cyl)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
    geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
            label = scales::percent((..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])), 
        stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
    facet_grid(.~ am) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name = " ") +
    labs(title = " ",
   x = " ",
   y = " ")
p

# my df:

p = ggplot(kc, aes(x = V1n, fill = V1)) + 
 geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])) + 
 scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
 geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
            label = scales::percent((..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])), 
        stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
 facet_grid(.~ METING.f) +
scale_fill_discrete(name = "Beschikt uw instelling over  een\naandachtsfunctionaris kindermishandeling?\n") +
labs(title = " ",
   x = "Vraag 1",
   y = "Percentage")
p
```

Comment: You'll have to more specific than "but it didn't work". A reproducible example would make it much more likely to get a good answer. Use `scale_fill_identity` perhaps.

Comment: thanks, i edited it and used mtcars as example, maybe now it's easier to understand what i should do..

Comment: Use `fill = factor(cyl)` instead.